# Combine data from two rows for calculate aggregate score

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a solution for storing my sports league fixtures and results and queries to extract the data and format a league table including application of additional match points for the team with the highest aggregate score from the two parts of the match.

The table structure is

--

### -- Table structure for table `fixtures`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fixtures` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `comp_id` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `hteam_id` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ateam_id` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `yzfixs` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `hscore1` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ascore1` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hscore2` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ascore2` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hbonus` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `abonus` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `played` varchar(2) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `adjusted` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `hadjust` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `aadjust` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `hreason` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `areason` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1127 ;

INSERT INTO `fixtures` (`id`, `comp_id`, `date`, `time`, `hteam_id`, `ateam_id`, `yzfixs`, `hscore1`, `ascore1`, `hscore2`, `ascore2`, `hbonus`, `abonus`, `played`, `adjusted`, `hadjust`, `aadjust`, `hreason`, `areason`) VALUES
(320, 2, '2015-09-29', NULL, 12, 13, '', 7, 9, 9, 10, 0, 2, 'Y', '', 0, 0, '', ''),
(319, 2, '2015-10-01', NULL, 11, 10, '', 8, 12, 12, 11, 0, 0, 'Y', '', 0, 0, '', ''),
```

For three of the four leagues I manage the data for the above works well, each match has two games hence the use of hscore1 (Home Score Game One), ascore1 (Away Score Game One), hscore2 (Home Score Game Two), ascore1 (Away Score Game Two).

The final output looks like this http://www.nicholastruscott.co.uk/2008site/index.php?pg=tabledisplay&comp_id=2

The fourth league has only one game for each match but two games added together for the aggregate score so I need to combine results from two rows.

I am planning to add a unique identifier to the records for each match making up a pair of matches but cannot get my head around combining each pair of match results to generate the league table using the same query as for the other three leagues.

Has anyone got any advise they can offer?

Many Thanks

Comment: You may want to consider normalizing your data to have the individual games ans results in a different table related to fixtures.

Comment: I don't understand "one game for each match but two games added together for the aggregate score". Is it one game or two games?

Comment: Did you mean to say "two **matches** added together"?

Comment: The three divisions match format is Team A plays Team B with two games played and six points on offer for the match.  Game results 10-7 and 7-9, each game has two points for win, one for draw.  The overall match score has a further two points available.  The other division is played differently with one game played for each fixture.  The Home and Away fixtures are added together to determine the further two points.